# vertical alignment issue with two divs

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have two divs within a datatable that I am trying to vertically align but having some issue. I would like to have them both aligned.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Each div has a class i.e. for export buttons .pull-left and for pagination .pull -right, css below:

I tried adding in vertical-align: middle or bottom etc but made no difference..

```
.pull-right {
    float:right;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.pull-left {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the html code from the console, there is too much code to paste in here

[image]

Here is also the sDom parameter I am using with datatables:

```
"sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-right'p><'pull-left'B>r<'clearfix'>>>t<'row'<'col-sm-12'<'pull-left'i><'pull-right'><'clearfix'>>>",
```

Comment: Can be achieved easily using datatables `sDom`

Comment: @claudios i have updated the post with the sDom i am using.. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you please add your full code here or in jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you trying to add custom buttons at the top?

Comment: @claudios just the standard buttons that come with Datatables. 'B' is for the export buttons and 'p' is for the pagination buttons.

Comment: could you show or let us know what's inside that class `pull-left` and `pull-right` content please?

Comment: @iMarkDesigns, i included that in my post?

Comment: ok, in my guess, one of the class at `pull-left` or `pull-right` have margin that can result of that. you might want to check the pagination or your icons btn-group if there's a margin that overlap the height of your container.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns,sorry wrong linke --- here is the btn-group css -> http://pastebin.com/biD9LWxk

Comment: if i can only see the whole code... i can help you right away with that. I do have same issues before, though i use FuelUX and wanted to add custom buttons similar at yours.

Comment: does this help? http://pasteboard.co/7CCKFmGO8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some solution to fix the the problem. But I would like to share to you these easy solution.

**First:** *Using bootstrap columns*

```
`"sDom": '<"col-xs-6" B><"col-xs-6" p>'`
```

**Second**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    } );
    $("div.toolbar").html('<b>add your buttons here</b>');
} );
```

**Third** Alternatively you can also do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

> Note: Remember to add the required scripts for the button to work.

**Fourth** using *CSS*:

```
.dt-buttons.btn-group {
  margin-bottom: -50px; //specify the margin here...
}
```

Comment: Wait. where did you put your pagination? is it under the table or at the top?

Comment: at the top. here is the whole table -> http://pasteboard.co/7Cjelg2sI.png

Comment: the fourth solution - updating the css margin seemed to have worked best. I had to make it -28px. Using the first option to update the dom, the pagination was still wraping to the next line, like so - see here: http://pasteboard.co/7CRAOMBTq.png

Comment: unfortunately, i cannot change the col size for less than 6 on B otherwise that will then wrap the export buttons to a new line..

Comment: Glad I could help :) maybe now you need to change your pagination like limit it unto 5 buttons

Answer (score 0):

When you use float the display property is no longer inline-block.on current situation you have to specify the width.
like .pull-right {widht:30%} .pull-left {width:60%}

or just give them display inline-block without float.as long as they are not meet there edge they are on same line.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it did not improve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `pull-left` & `pull-right` you can use `col-md-6` class for both `div` tags.

Comment: okay, I switched to this but it made it alot worse.. `"sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'p<'col-md-6'B>r<'clearfix'>>>"`

Comment: try `<'row'<'col-md-6'p><'col-md-6'B>r<'clearfix'>>`

Comment: Reduce the `col` size for buttons and increase for pagination, also check any top padding or margin added to pagination list